# Disable background color box on a click

Tags: css, wordpress

so if I click on header menu item, background also changes - how to avoid that?
[image]

[See here](https://www.mrhack.io)

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way to disable that behavior, but this does the trick

```
.w-nav .menu-item .ripple-container {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This also seems to work: .w-nav .menu-item .ripple-container {
  color: transparent;
}